# How to subquery three tables in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

**Problem:**

I have a table "disabled_product" in which i have product_id, menu_id, branch_id.

> I want to get all records from disabled_product where product_id = 4,
> and where product_id, menu_id in disabled_product match
> the product_id, menu_id in menu_product

AND

> menu_id, branch_id in disabled_product match the menu_id, branch_id in
> branch_menu table.

I wrote a query but its throwing me an error "Cardinality violation: 1242" because both the tables menu_product and branch_menu have multiple records matching. I don't how should i subquery disabled_product and get only those records which matches to menu_product and branch_menu.

Any help is appreciated.

**Query:**

```
$disabledProduct = DisabledProduct::where('branch_id', function ($query) use ($productID) {
                $query->from('branch_menu')
                    ->select('branch_menu.branch_id')
                    ->where('branch_menu.menu_id', function ($query) use ($productID) {
                        $query->from('menu_product')
                            ->select('menu_product.menu_id')
                            ->where('menu_product.menu_id', function ($query) use ($productID) {
                                $query->from('menu_product')
                                    ->select('menu_product.menu_id')
                                    ->where('menu_product.product_id', $productID);
                            });
                    });
            })
            ->where('product_id', $productID)
```

**disabled_product Table:**

[image]

**menu_product Table:**

[image]

**branch_menu Table:**

[image]

Comment: Have you defined any model relationships?

Comment: menu_product has many to many relationship with each other and so does the branch_menu but disabled_product does not have any relation with either table

Answer (score 1):

Try this using **Subquery Where Clauses**,

```php
$productId = 4;

 $disabledProducts = DisabledProduct::query()
    ->where('product_id', function ($query) {
        $query->from('menu_product')
              ->select('product_id')
              ->where('menu_id', function ($query) {
                  $query->from('branch_menu')
                        ->select('menu_id')
                        ->whereRaw('branch_id = `disabled_product`.`branch_id`');
              });
    })
    ->where('product_id', $productId)
    ->get();
```